# How to get rows from HTML string table created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML table using JavaScript:

```
function CreateArray(){
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){    
    arr.push({
      firstName:"John",
      lastName:"Doe",
      email:"email"+i.toString()+"@gmail.com"
    }); 
  } 
  return arr;
}

function CreateTable(data) {   
  var tableStr = [];
  var j = -1;

  tableStr[++j] = '<table class="tftable" border="1"><thead><tr><th><input type="checkbox" id="allEmails" onclick = "SelectAllEmails()"/></th><th>First Name</th><th>Family Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tableStr[++j] = '<tr><td>';
    tableStr[++j] = '<input type= "checkbox"';
    tableStr[++j] = 'id =' + "chbxEmail" + i.toString() +" "+'onclick =' + "foo(this)"+" "+'/>';
    tableStr[++j] = '</td><td>';
    tableStr[++j] =  data[i].firstName;
    tableStr[++j] = '</td><td>';
    tableStr[++j] = data[i].lastName;
    tableStr[++j] = '</td><td>';
    tableStr[++j] = data[i].email;
    tableStr[++j] = '</td></tr>';
  }
  tableStr[++j] = '</tbody></table>';
  var table = tableStr.join('');
}
```

I need to get all rows inside the HTML table except the header row.
I've tried it this way:

```
var trows =  table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows;
alert(trows.length);
```

But I don't get any result. Even the alert box is not displayed.

How can I get the rows inside the table variable without the header row?

Comment: Where are called the code with alert ? Anyway is much better to use a Framework like AngularJs or knockoutJs.

Comment: Because your table isn't created in the DOM yet. Without a framework, you can only create DOM elements one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript :

```
document.querySelectorAll('#table-id tr:not(:first-child)')
```

Another solution using Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('table-id').children[1].children
```

Using JQuery :

```
$('#table-id tr:not(:first-child)')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you probably didn't insert your table into the HTML DOM. Otherwise it should work. You may also consider using the `querySelector` function instead of `getElementsByTagName`, so e.g. `var rows = document.querySelector('tbody tr');`

Answer (score 0):

I use insertAdjacentHTML to parse string to HTML DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML